# Is there a switch-case equivalent for laravel eloquent query when()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, switch-statement, custom-sort

I'm just curious if there's a switch-case equivalent for **when()** query

I want this code to use when() with default (if no "when" are used)

```
public function scopeSortBy(Builder $query, $field, $dir = 'asc')
{
    switch ($field) {

        case 'fullName':
            $query->orderBy('last_name', $dir)
                ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc');
            break;

        case 'custom_sort_1':
            // Need to implement

            break;


        case 'custom_sort_2':
            // Need to implement

            break;

        default:
            $query->orderBy($field, $dir);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`when`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.html#method_when) method available, hence you could modify your query as

```
public function scopeSortBy(Builder $query, $field, $dir = 'asc')
{
    $query->when(! empty($field), function ($query) use ($dir) {
        $query->orderBy($field, $dir);
    });

    $query->when($field == 'fullName', function ($query) use ($dir) {
        $query->orderBy('last_name', $dir)
            ->orderBy('first_name', $dir);
    })

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want to know if there is a counter-part of switch-case with `when()` where the default will be use if the `$field` is not on the 'cases'